# Firebase / Firestore - How to manually create indexes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a mobile app with react-native.
I am using a third party template to get going.
This templates creates a Firestore database collection named "users".
This template also keeps giving me errors about not having an index on that "users" collection:

```
[FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/social-marketplace-3c8df/firestore/indexes?create_composite=CmRwcm9qZWN0cy9zb2NpYWwtbWFya2V0cGxhY2UtM2M4ZGYvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL1NvY2lhbE5ldHdvcmtfUG9zdHMvaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaDAoIYXV0aG9ySUQQARoNCgljcmVhdGVkQXQQAhoMCghfX25hbWVfXxAC]
```

When I copy this "create index" link from the error message and paste it into the browser, it takes me to an empty Firebase console page. No indexes being created as the result of this.
WhenI attempt to manually create such index by navigating to the "indexes" tab on the Firestore page, selecting composite index, and entering "/users" as my collection name, I'm being told that "/users" is reserved, so I am unable to create such index.
Is there a way to create such an index on my "/users" collection?

Comment: You could create the indexes manually via the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/social-marketplace-3c8df/firestore/indexes) but normally the link provided in the error message should work.

Comment: I am trying - I am entering "users" for the collection name, but the "Create Index" button remains disabled

Comment: Have you noted that you need to scroll down in the dialog box to choose the "Query scopes"?

Comment: Now, that you pointed that out - I added two field names and the scope, and "create Index" button lit up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can create a file `firestore.indexes.json`
Leter create your index:

```
 {
      "indexes": [
        {
          "collectionGroup": "collection_name",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
          "fields": [
            {
              "fieldPath": "your_field_name",
              "order": "ASCENDING"
            },
            {
              "fieldPath": "your_field_name",
              "order": "DESCENDING"
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
```

Remember:
CollectionGroup = collection name

queryScope = type (collection | document)

fields = fields for orderBy

singleField = only field for orderBy

Answer (score 0):

As @Renaud Tarnec's comment it fixed by using the **Firebase console** in :

1. **Cloud Firestore** > **Indexes** panel > Click **Add Index** button.
2. Input **"users"** or value in **Collection ID** text-box.
3. In Field to index, add at least **two fields** - this is required
4. **Scroll down** > Query scopes > Select if **Collection** or **Collection Group**
5. And it will enable the **Create index** button.